# How to contribute incrementally to Theoretical CS - similar to github

Tags: cc.complexity-theory

I have been through all the basic undergrad classes in CS. I have finished a masters in CS. I have learned a decent amount about applying Haskell to engineering. I haven't studied abstract math yet. I have attended two STOC conferences. I have about 2 hours per week that I could contribute in some way to move Theoretical CS forward in some way.

For Haskell, I could spend that time writing documentation, adding test suites, or implementing features for open source Haskell libraries on github. Is there an equivalent way incrementally contribute as a beginner to theoretical CS? Is there anything like github or are people using github for such purposes?

The best idea I have currently is to try to teach undergrad discrete math or algorithm courses.

Comment: Well, there is that: https://thmatters.wordpress.com/2017/05/02/tcs-wikipedia-project/

Answer (score 8):

As mentioned in a comment above, you can contribute to the [TCS Wikipedia Project](https://thmatters.wordpress.com/2017/05/02/tcs-wikipedia-project/) led by [Shuchi Chawla](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~shuchi/):

> Wikipedia is a great resource for people outside of the TCS community to learn about TCS topics, and provides an educational and outreach opportunity for our community. Our community should ensure that important TCS topics get adequate and accurate coverage in Wikipedia through articles written by experts. Unfortunately, writing or editing articles for Wikipedia, and ensuring that the edits are not overwritten, can be a daunting task. It is a task best addressed as a community effort rather than by a few individuals.